# What are the risks on public wifi if using https?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, https

Let's assume I'm on a public, unsecured wifi and malicious hackers have full access to it.

If I'm only using https,what are the risks?

Comment: I do not use these setups. You do not know what might happen. I use my phone or my USB internet sick for Internet Access. That is much safer.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/176025/123296 may help

Answer (score 0):

If the hacker controls the local DNS server, then it can redirect your
connection to its own website to establish its server as man-in-the-middle
and connect to the website as your agent.

This means that the hacker can read all your sensitive data.

Don't try to outsmart the hackers - You stand no chance in that competition.
Don't enter sensitive information on public WiFi unless you have full
confidence in its integrity.

Comment: This will only work on unencrypted (http) connections. However if your connection is not encrypted and the hacker is controlling the WiFi access point / router then he can just listen in on the communication, there is no need to have its own server. On secure connections (https) the browser will prevent you from accessing a 'fake' server as it doesn't have a certificate matching the server name.